# Search List-of-Lists within a List-of-Lists/LoL?

Tags: python, list, search

Let say I have LoL I want to be able to find if a sub-list can be found in this big LoL and how many times it occurs.

Here is an example of the LoL (it could be much bigger ) :

```
  [[[['a'], ['g']], [['g'], ['b']]], [[['g'], ['e']], [['e'], ['b']]], [[['f'], ['h']], [['g'], ['b']]], [[['g'], ['e']], [['g'], ['b']]], [[['e'], ['b']], [['g'], ['e']]]]
```

and here are some examples of LoL I could be searching for :

```
  [[['a'], ['g']], [['g'], ['b']]]

  [['a'], ['g']]

  ['a']
```

Comment: LoL = list of lists?

Comment: yes the helper told me not to repeat words in the question header ... thats why I put LoL

Answer (score 1):

I think string containment checking should be enough.

```
>>> l = [[[['a'], ['g']], [['g'], ['b']]], [[['g'], ['e']], [['e'], ['b']]], [[['f'], ['h']], [['g'], ['b']]], [[['g'], ['e']], [['g'], ['b']]], [[['e'], ['b']], [['g'], ['e']]]]
>>> str_l = str(l)
>>> str([[['a'], ['g']], [['g'], ['b']]]) in str_l
True
>>> str([['a'], ['g']]) in str_l
True
>>> str([[['a'], ['g']], [['x'], ['b']]]) in str_l
False
```

For count you can just use `str.count`:

```
>>> str_l.count(str([['g'], ['b']]))
3
```

Comment: clever, but it does not count the matches ? may be index()!! should try it

Comment: @sten you can just call `str.count`, edited the answer, and yes, you can use `index()` too to get which indices it found the matches in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` to check if the search data exists in the List of Lists:

```py
lol = [[[['a'], ['g']], [['g'], ['b']]], [[['g'], ['e']], [['e'], ['b']]], [[['f'], ['h']], [['g'], ['b']]], [[['g'], ['e']], [['g'], ['b']]], [[['e'], ['b']], [['g'], ['e']]]]

search_data1 = [[['a'], ['g']], [['g'], ['b']]]

if search_data1 in lol:
    print(search_data1)
else:
    print('Not found!')
```